# Partial specialization is not more specialized

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++14, partial-specialization

To my surprise, I got an error, when I tried to compile this code with `GCC 7.2.0`.

Code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Seq, typename Seq::value_type Inc> struct increment;
template <typename T, T... I, T Inc>                                   
struct increment<std::integer_sequence<T,I...>, Inc> {                 
  using type = std::integer_sequence<T,(I+Inc)...>;                    
};                                                                     

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  typename increment<std::make_index_sequence<2>,1>::type seq;
  std::cout << typeid(seq).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
error: partial specialization 'struct increment<std::integer_sequence<T, I ...>, Inc>' is not more specialized than [-fpermissive]
 struct increment<std::integer_sequence<T,I...>, Inc> {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
spec.cc:5:62: note: primary template 'template<class Seq, typename Seq::value_type Inc> struct increment'
 template <typename Seq, typename Seq::value_type Inc> struct increment;
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~
```

I've been using `increment` for quite a while now with `GCC 6.2.0` without a problem.

Which one is correct? If `GCC 7` is correct, how do I write this metafunction?

Comment: `typename std::integer_sequence<T,I...>::value_type Inc`

Comment: Hmm, alright. That worked. But the `value_type` and `T` are the same type, so why can't `T` be used?

Comment: @T.C. Why? And gcc compiles it with in c++17 mode.